# ASP.NET WebAPI - Upload big files using streaming

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, streaming, uploading

I have the following business requirements:
User should be able to upload files (max file size should be 20GB) to ASP.NET MVC web site and then this web site should pass these files to ASP.NET Web API web service and then web api will save these files to hard drive.
The problem is: ASP.NET and IIS have limitations for file size - 2 GB (this is max size). 
My questions is: how to implement these requirements? And how to do it in the best way (may be I should use file streaming or divide big files to smaller)?
I will very appreciate for any good detailed advices!
Thanks.

Comment: Network share is probably the better idea for this requirement

Comment: Unfortunately, its impossible :(